# TypeError: plot_topomap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vmin'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data = pd.Series([-0.5, -0.7, -0.3, 0.1, 0.15, 0.3, 0.55],
index=['F3', 'Fz', 'F4', 'C3', 'Cz', 'C4', 'Pz'])
fig = yasa.topoplot(data, vmin=-1, vmax=1, n_colors=8,
                cbar_title="Pearson correlation")
```

TypeError: plot_topomap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vmin'

Did anyone solve this problem when trying to use yasa.topolot? I'm using yasa 0.6.3 and mne 1.6.0, any help appreciated! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [current issue at GitHub](https://github.com/raphaelvallat/yasa/issues/140) that's the same of your problem:

> While using `topoplot()` function, I get an error that `mne.viz.plot_topomap()` does not have some parameters (`vmin` and `vmax`, instead it only has a `vlim` parameter which takes a tuple of the two limits). I solved this by updating the function parameters as they are on the *mne* documentation. I suppose the *mne* library was updated, but the current *yasa* version uses the old version of *mne*.

The solution currently is either

1. remove your current *yasa* package using `python -m pip uninstall yasa` and install directly from GitHub (where it's supposedly fixed) using

   ```bash
   python -m pip install git+https://github.com/raphaelvallat/yasa
   ```
2. since the [`yasa.topoplat` function](https://raphaelvallat.com/yasa/build/html/generated/yasa.topoplot.html) is only a wrapper, use directly the [`mne.viz.plot_topomap` function](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.viz.plot_topomap.html), setting the `vlim` parameter to `(-1, 1)`